# Invalid parameter `publish' for `POST videos in Dailymotion Live stream Api

Tags: stream, live, dailymotion-api

I'm trying to use Dailymotion api for create Live stream. But it does not work with `publish` parameter.

> {"error":{"more_info":"https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#error-codes","code":400,"message":"Invalid parameter `publish' for`POST /videos'","type":"invalid_parameter"}}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is a typo in the documentation, the right name of the field is 'published' instead of 'publish'.
We will quickly fix the documentation.
Thank you for your feedback.